# QBS: qbs-setup-qt fails to detect target platform

Tags: qt, qbs

### Background

I have cross-compiled Qt for ARM target using the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` toolchain.

running `qmake -query` gives (among other values) `QMAKE_XSPEC:arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`.

When running `qbs-setup-qt <path to the qmake> armqt` I get empty (`""`) value for `Qt.core`'s `tragetPlatform` property for the `armqt` profile. I would expect to get `"linux"`.

This causes a failure when loading the `Qt.core` module, which has a condition that forces `qbs.targetPlatform === targetPlatform`. Here `qbs.targetPlatform` equals `"linux"` while `targetPlatform` is empty.

The target platform is determined in `qtprofilesetup.cpp` at the function `qbsTargetPlatformFromQtMkspec`. It looks for QMAKE_XSPEC values **starting** with `"linux-"`

### My question

Is there a way to avoid this false detection?
I can patch the code to allow the 'linux' to appear after the first'-' or something like that, but I'm not sure it has other effects.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does this Qt installation come from? A Linux distribution?

Comment: Oh, you nailed it, @Christian. I had Qt compiled from source using my own mkspec directory, which I had named `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`. This was in contrast to the convention of starting the directory name with the platform name. That was harmless, until Qbs got into the picture. I renamed my mkspec directory to begin with `linux-`, and now Qbs detects my platform correctly. Thanks.

Comment: That's good to hear. Sometimes Linux distributions don't follow the convention, e.g. Fedora names their mingw mkspecs "mingw-something" instead of "win32-g++-something", which also used to cause problems with qbs. So I was worried we'd have another instance of that here.